# Selection of specific value from dropdown

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to pass the specific value of country to get selected from a dropdown
but I am unable to do so with the following code:

```
wd.FindElement(By.Id("CountrySelector")).Click(); 
new SelectElement(wd.FindElement(By.Id("CountrySelector"))).SelectByText("Philippines-Philippine Peso(PhP)");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with the c#-implementation of selenium, just java. Maybe there is just some missing whitespace or something like that. Please try the following:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='CountrySelector']//option[text()='Philippines-Philippine Peso(PhP)']"));
Assert.assertTrue(webElement.isDisplayed());
```

(Sorry, it's java, maybe you must alter the code, but i guess you get the idea...)